# Love in a hating way

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, collocation, literary-english

Is there a single word (or a two-word phrase at least) that means "love in a hating way (hatefully, execrably)"?

There is the term "Love–hate relationship" but it is more of a psychological term:

> A love–hate relationship is an interpersonal relationship involving simultaneous or alternating emotions of love and hate—something particularly common when emotions are intense. - *[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Love%E2%80%93hate_relationship)*

I'm mainly looking for a noun (or possibly an adjective or a verb).

An example sentence:

> This ____, in which they hate each other lovingly or love hatefully, in which the contrasting feelings transcend each other. It is so hurtful yet comforting, so wearing yet pleasant.

Comment: "Love in a hating way"? Marriage. :P

Comment: Not a perfect fit, but a word in common vernacular today in the US that is similar is frenemy. "Oh, Alexis and Sarah? They are totally frenemies" Meaning to be cordial toward each other and polite when face-to-face, but talking about one another behind backs.

Comment: _Ōdi et amō, quāre id faciam fortasse requīrīs… Nesciō, sed fierī sentiō et excrucior._

Comment: Catullus on ELU. Never thought I'd see the day :D

Comment: I don't totally get the question. Does it mean that you love someone but he/she totally pisses you off? Or does it mean that you love to hate the person, and you enjoy being around them for that reason?

Comment: I've updated my question from ~8 years ago to make in on-topic and I've voted to re-open. This is the first time I've done something like this in my journey here :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like "brawling love", because I like quoting Shakespeare.

He was neither the first nor the last to discuss relationships combining love and hate (nor was that his only time), so there are in fact thousands of different phrases describing it. So many in fact that I'd avoid set phrases that have been used before; see if this tired old trope can be made fresh again!

Comment: I want that glib and oily art
To speak and purpose not, since what I well intend,
I'll do't before I speak. - "King Lear"

Answer (score 3):

> ***Ambivalence***
>   To have two conflicting emotions simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

You could try 'a cynical relationship'?

Comment: I think this is more like not believing in love.

Answer (score 0):

[Frenemy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frenemy), defined on Google at the moment as "a person with whom one is friendly despite a fundamental dislike or rivalry."